# Using API Gateway as Reverse Proxy for Web Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, reverse-proxy, aws-api-gateway

I've been using API Gateway as a reverse proxy for my backed RESTful services, but when I try to serve html content it doesn't seem to work.  I just get an empty response body.

Is API Gateway strictly meant for API's or can it work for web pages and other web content as well?  If not, is there another AWS service that can work as a reverse proxy for this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway can work with HTML content. You need to either send the "Accept:text/html" header in the request, or explicitly add "Content-Type" header in the method response and map it to 'text/html' in the integration response.